# How to cure extremely messed up resolutions on Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution

I have just now installed nvidia drivers on my Ubuntu box and realized that the resolutions are very very messed up. On windows which is supposed to share the PC with Ubuntu the screen operates flawlessly at a resolution 1600x900 whereas on Ubuntu the resolution is (Spoiler: Its not gr8) 1024x768. I am using a samsung sync-master 2033 monitor connected with a VGA cable for my primary and only monitor. My mind and eyes alike would appreciate any help. Thanks in Advance.

Bonus fact: when I used Xorg and not proprietary drivers I could achieve higher resolution using xrandr but now when i use the commands it (the terminal) says:

```
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1440x900_60.00                                  !103
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  34
here
```

Comment: Sometimes the built-in linux drivers are better than the proprietary driver, but we must not give up yet with the nvidia proprietary drivers -- Please tell us the nvidia chip/card model number and the version of the nvidia graphics driver. Somebody (probably not me) might recognize them and help you get further.

Comment: Damn fixed it. Stupid Nvidia. this answer (https://askubuntu.com/questions/721186/cant-get-hd-resolution-working-on-second-monitor-nvidia-gt640-card-ubuntu-14-0?rq=1) was a hell lot of help.

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for sharing your solution :-)